# How to get users whose location matches an entered location

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create an application where a user can enter a location and search for doctors surrounding that location. An admin will be adding doctors with their details along with location.

I am learning mongodb and I am wondering what would be the efficient way to do this.

I am planing to use google's [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests).

My question is how should I store the doctor's location and how can I retrieve doctor's surrounding the searched location.

I thought I could do this:

When a doctor is saved, I could call the API and search for places that are near the doctor's saved location and then save the nearby locations in an array. When a patient searches a location, I will search the locations array of each doctor and if the searched text matches the item in array, I will return those doctors.

But this does not seem very efficient. Can somebody suggest how I can do this?

Comment: Have you looked at 2dsphere indexes and $geoNear?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latitude and longitude of the place from Places API. While the admin adds the doctor, use the same Places API to get the corresponding latitude and longitude. Now you can use some distance matrix to check how close they are as you have both the doctors and the user latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at geoSpatial queries in mongodb: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

Storage pattern is:

```
location: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [-73.856077, 40.848447]
}
```

After this you need to put geo index and then the query with $near will work: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Another approach that you can take is calculate approximate min and max latitude and longitude and optimize your query. For this to work storage will look like:

```
location: {
    lat: <num>,
    long: <num>,
}
```

So you want to find all the docter closest to a point with A (lat: , long: ) 
Approximate the Lat(max) and Long(max), Lat(min) and Long(min) using the below method. And query the database by simple range query.

Similar to this document: http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

Answer (score 0):

You do not need anything complex or dependent on APIs and database to do that. Just get the customer coordinate and the range it is willing to travel. You then can calculate a square that covers the chosen range circle and use the latitude and longitude to query available doctors with >= and <=.

This offers the advantage to serve not only for the actual customer coordinate but for any coordinate in the map.

It is not 100% precise but is simple, gives good performance and is acceptable for most use cases.

```
SELECT d
  FROM doctors
WHERE latitude <= :customer_max_latitute
  AND latitude >= :customer_min_latitute
  AND longitute <= :customer_max_logintude
  AND logitute >= :customer_min_logitude
```

[image: Customer willing rage x doctors result]